# Сохранить в массив ассоциативный массив JS

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = {
 status: true,
 id: 1
}

let mass= [];
```

Как можно в mass сохранить несколько obj. Знаю, xчто путем цикла, но как присвоить элементу массива ассоциативный массив целиком?

Comment: Что значит "_присвоить элементу массива ассоциативный массив целиком_"(с) ?

Comment: Ассоциативных массивов в стандартном JS нет, вместо них используются объекты. Запись в элемент массива ссылки на объект (объекты всегда передаются по ссылке) - ничем не отличается от записи значений любых других типов: можно и присваиванием по индексу, и методами (push/unshift/splice), и созданием нового массива с rest-оператором, и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
  status: true,
  id: 1
}

let mass = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  mass.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
console.log(mass);
```